# Storing a JsonObject into an HasMap

Tags: java, android, android-json, gson

I am getting below jsonResponse.

***In Every response Both key and value changes.***

I want to store **count** & **previousCountDay** , keys and values in **HashMap**.

**Json Response:**

```
{
    "count": {
        "2018-03-28 18": 55,
        "2018-03-28 19": 48,
        "2018-03-28 20": 41,
        "2018-03-28 21": 31,
        "2018-03-28 22": 32,
        "2018-03-28 23": 26,
        "2018-03-29 00": 20,
        "2018-03-29 01": 16,
        "2018-03-29 02": 12,
        "2018-03-29 03": 0
    },
    "previousCountDay": {
        "2018-03-27 18": 40,
        "2018-03-27 19": 59,
        "2018-03-27 20": 53,
        "2018-03-27 21": 48,
        "2018-03-27 22": 36,
        "2018-03-27 23": 40,
        "2018-03-28 00": 37,
        "2018-03-28 01": 14,
        "2018-03-28 02": 29,
        "2018-03-28 03": 1
    }, 
    "noOfIntervals": 10,
    "range": [
        "18",
        "19",
        "20",
        "21",
        "22",
        "23",
        "00",
        "01",
        "02",
        "03"
    ]
}
```

By using GSON I am getting JSON response but I am storing only `range` because it's coming in JSON Array, By `range` i am getting the size of `count` & `previousCountDay`.

Below is my **Activity Class:**

```
 private void JsonRequestOrderVelocity(String dmhw) {
    utils.showDialog();

    String url = Constants.VELOCITY_API;
    Log.e("URL", "" + url);

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(url, null,
            response -> {
                Log.e("onResponse",""+response);
                try {
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    Type listType = new TypeToken<OrderVelocityPojo>() {
                    }.getType();

                    orderVelocityPojo = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), listType);

                    Log.e("SIZE",""+orderVelocityPojo.getRange().size());

                    JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject("count");

                    Map<String, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

                    //store keys and values in HashMap.
                    for(int i=0;i<orderVelocityPojo.getRange().size();i++){

                       countMap.put( ); 

                    }



                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Exception",""+e);
                    utils.hideDialog();
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
                utils.hideDialog();

            }, error -> {

        Log.e("error",""+error.getMessage());
        utils.hideDialog();
    });
    request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            MY_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    AppController.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(request);
}
```

**OrderVelocityPojo**  Pojo class :

```
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class OrderVelocityPojo {

    @SerializedName("noOfIntervals")
    @Expose
    private Integer noOfIntervals;

    @SerializedName("range")
    @Expose
    private List<String> range = null; 


    public Integer getNoOfIntervals() {
        return noOfIntervals;
    }

    public void setNoOfIntervals(Integer noOfIntervals) {
        this.noOfIntervals = noOfIntervals;
    }

    public List<String> getRange() {
        return range;
    }

    public void setRange(List<String> range) {
        this.range = range;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your OrderVelocityPojo class? Since keys are changing, it's difficult to define a Pojo to deserialise the json. You can deserialise the json into Object or Map<Object, Object>, in either case GSON will form a nested Map from your response. You can fetch count- map from the map. Although you have to perform some type-casting.

Comment: I added my pojo class @Debanjan

Comment: If "count" key does not change, you can add Map<String, Integer> count ; in your pojo. Else you may have to give away your POJO and use Map<String, Object> instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also add data manually using iterating keys of `JSONObject`.

Here is sample code.

```
        HashMap<String, String> count = new HashMap<>();
        HashMap<String, String> previousCountDay = new HashMap<>();
        try {
            JSONObject mJsonObjectMain = new JSONObject("your json string");
            JSONObject mJsonObjectCount = mJsonObjectMain.getJSONObject("count");
            Iterator a = mJsonObjectCount.keys();
            while (a.hasNext()) {
                String key = (String) a.next();
                // loop to get the dynamic key
                String value = (String) mJsonObjectCount.get(key);
                System.out.print("key : " + key);
                System.out.println(" value :" + value);
                count.put(key, value);
            }

            JSONObject mJsonObjectPreviousCount = mJsonObjectMain.getJSONObject("previousCountDay");
            //do same as above
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**Final Code :**

```
HashMap<String, Integer> count = new HashMap<>();
                     try {
                        JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject("count");
                        Iterator a = object.keys();
                        while (a.hasNext()) {
                            String key = (String) a.next();
                            // loop to get the dynamic key
                            Integer value = (Integer) object.get(key);
                            Log.e("count : ","Keys :"+ key+"   Values :"+value);
                            count.put(key, value);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library for this.
You can try converting json object to hashmap. Here you will provide typeToken as your json type value.

```
Map<String, Object> hashmap = new Gson().fromJson(
    jsonString, new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Object>>() {}.getType()
);
```